# Does Master of the Wild Hunt deal damage multiple times?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The text on the [Master of the Wild Hunt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Master%20of%20the%20Wild%20Hunt) card:

> At the beginning of your upkeep, put a 2/2 green Wolf creature token onto the battlefield.

> Tap: Tap all untapped Wolf creatures you control. Each Wolf tapped this way deals damage equal to its power to target creature. That creature deals damage equal to its power divided as its controller chooses among any number of those Wolves.

The text states that each wolf deals damage.  This implies that there are multiple damage sources.  Can all of this damage be prevented at once, or need it be prevented from each source individually?

For example, look at [Unbreathing Horde](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Unbreathing%20Horde):

> Unbreathing Horde enters the battlefield with a +1/+1 counter on it for each other Zombie you control and each Zombie card in your graveyard.

> If Unbreathing Horde would be dealt damage, prevent that damage and remove a +1/+1 counter from it.

If multiple wolves deal damage to Unbreathing Horde simultaneously per **Master of the Wild Hunt's** activated ability, does it remove one +1/+1 counter per wolf, or just one +1/+1 counter?

Comment: no, not unless first strike is involved. See: http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=37113 for card with similar text and a ruling stating as much.

Comment: @ColinD First strike doesn't have anything to do with this, because this isn't an attack, just damage being dealt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The text states that each wolf deals damage. This implies that there are multiple damage sources.

This is correct, but it's not relevant.

If you used [Master of the Wild Hunt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Master%20of%20the%20Wild%20Hunt)'s second ability targeting an [Unbreathing Horde](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Unbreathing%20Horde), at most one counter would end up being removed no matter how many wolves you have.  All the wolves deal their damage simultaneously, so the Horde is only dealt damage once, even if the damage comes from multiple sources. Unbreathing Horde's replaces the receiving of damage, not the receiving of damage by a source.

Compare

"If Unbreathing Horde would be dealt damage,"

with

"If Unbreathing Horde would be dealt damage by a source,"

[Phantom Nishoba](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Phantom%20Nishoba) has a ruling confirming this.

Comment: I am confused. Wouldn't Unbreathing Horde get dealt damage a number of times equal to the wolves in play? Then it's ability would trigger that many times? So if there were 7 wolves, then it would end up losing 7 +1/+1 counters?

Comment: @Milo Gertjejansen, Nope, all the wolves deal their damage simultaneously, so the Horde is only dealt damage once. If it meant to replace damage dealt by a source, it would [say so](http://magiccards.info/mt/en/2.html).

Comment: I see. It has more to do with the *timing* of the damage, not the number of sources. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Yep, and similarly, when creatures in combat deal damage, they all do so at the same time (unless first strike or double strike are involved). So all combat damage in this case counts as one instance of dealing damage, even if it is coming from multiple sources.

Comment: @David Z, What are you talking about? There is no combat damage in this case.

Comment: @ikegami I was simply pointing out that combat is another case where multiple sources deal damage at the same time.